# Apple Watch series 6 battery draining

Tags: battery, apple-watch, watchos

hello to apple community.
I just bought a new series 6 Apple Watch but I think the battery drains so fast!
for example when it is in sleep in about 2 hours it uses 4% battery I just wanted to know if it is normal or not.
I also turned off always on screen, background apps refresh.
the OS is fully up to date.

thanks for your help

Comment: If you extrapolate that you get 50 hours of runtime. Seems pretty normal to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that seems quite normal.

I'm used to charging my Apple Watch at least every other day, so that matches your experience. It was roughly the same experience with older models of the watch.

Comment: Nice contribution!

Comment: @jkseogaard thanks a lot for your help. I was a little bit worried about it